# Excel 2010 Paste Range and Picture into Outlook

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I am having considerable difficulty figuring this one out. I can paste a range as HTML without issues, but in some communications we want to past the range as a picture instead.  I can create a range and save it as a picture, but I cannot figure out how to past the picture into Outlook after it is created.

If you are just looking for code that will copy a range and paste it into Outlook, this works great.  All of the email data is referencing cells on a tab called Mail, so you can simply copy and paste the Mail tab and the macro into any workbook and add email automation by editing the fields on the mail tab and not changing the macro.  If you use this code, make sure to reference Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library (In VBA Window: Tools - References - Microsoft Outlook x.x Object Library).

I need to take this one step further and be able to turn the range into a picture and paste it into the email. I can attach it, but I cannot insert it into the body, which is what I need.  I have looked at several examples, including those on Ron DeBruins website, but I have not been able to get any of them to work.  I am running Windows 7 x64 With Office 2010 x64.

Here is the code I am running to paste a range.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mail_AS_Range()

' Working in Office 2010-2013
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String

On Error Resume Next

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Mail")
strbody = sh.Range("C9").Value
Sheets(sh.Range("C11").Value).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Save


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = sh.Range("C4")  'This allows us to send from an alternate email address
    .Display  'Alternate send address will not work if we do not display the email first.
              'I dont know why but this step is a MUST
    .To = sh.Range("C5")
    .CC = sh.Range("C6")
    .BCC = sh.Range("C7")
    .Subject = sh.Range("C8").Value
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & fncRangeToHtml(sh.Range("C13").Value, sh.Range("C14").Value) & .HTMLBody
                ' This is where the body of the email is pulled together.
                ' <br> is an HTML tag to turn the text into HTML
                ' strbody is your text from cell C9 on the mail tab
                ' fncRangetoHtml is converting the range you specified into HTML
                ' .HTMLBody inserts your email signature
    .Attachments.Add sh.Range("C10").Value
    '.Send

End With

On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub


 Private Function fncRangeToHtml( _
 strWorksheetName As String, _
 strRangeAddress As String) As String

' This is creating a private function to make the range specified in the Mail macro into HTML

 Dim objFilesytem As Object, objTextstream As Object, objShape As Shape
 Dim strFilename As String, strTempText As String
 Dim blnRangeContainsShapes As Boolean

 strFilename = Environ$("temp") & "\" & _
     Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy_h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

 ThisWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=strFilename, _
     Sheet:=strWorksheetName, _
     Source:=strRangeAddress, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish True

 Set objFilesytem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objTextstream = objFilesytem.GetFile(strFilename).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 strTempText = objTextstream.ReadAll
 objTextstream.Close
 strTempText = Replace(strTempText, "align=center x:publishsource=", "align=left x:publishsource=")

 For Each objShape In Worksheets(strWorksheetName).Shapes
     If Not Intersect(objShape.TopLeftCell, Worksheets( _
         strWorksheetName).Range(strRangeAddress)) Is Nothing Then

         blnRangeContainsShapes = True
         Exit For

     End If
 Next

 If blnRangeContainsShapes Then strTempText = fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText, Worksheets(strWorksheetName))

 fncRangeToHtml = strTempText

 Set objTextstream = Nothing
 Set objFilesytem = Nothing

 Kill strFilename

 End Function

 Public Function fncConvertPictureToMail(strTempText As String, objWorksheet As Worksheet) As String

 Const HTM_START = "<link rel=File-List href="
 Const HTM_END = "/filelist.xml"

 Dim strTemp As String
 Dim lngPathLeft As Long

 lngPathLeft = InStr(1, strTempText, HTM_START)

 strTemp = Mid$(strTempText, lngPathLeft, InStr(lngPathLeft, strTempText, ">") - lngPathLeft)
 strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_START & Chr$(34), "")
 strTemp = Replace(strTemp, HTM_END & Chr$(34), "")
 strTemp = strTemp & "/"

 strTempText = Replace(strTempText, strTemp, Environ$("temp") & "\" & strTemp)

 fncConvertPictureToMail = strTempText

 End Function
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://vba-useful.blogspot.com/2014/01/send-html-email-with-embedded-images.html

Comment: It will need some adaptation but this is going to work, even better than I expected!  I'll post the revised code that works in my project.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to BP_ who directed me to a link, which answered my question.  Here is my code after modifying for my application.

This allows me to set all the variables within a tab in Excel and not edit the query itself.  I use this method because some folks on my team are not comfortable editing VBA.

```
Sub Mail_W_Pic()

Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strbody As String
Dim width As String
Dim height As String

On Error Resume Next

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Mail")
strbody = sh.Range("C9").Value
Sheets(sh.Range("C11").Value).Select
width = (sh.Range("C15").Value)
height = (sh.Range("C16").Value)

    'Create a new Microsoft Outlook session
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    'create a new message
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = sh.Range("C4")
        .Display
        .Subject = sh.Range("C8").Value
        .To = sh.Range("C5")
        .CC = sh.Range("C6")
        .BCC = sh.Range("C7")
        'first we create the image as a JPG file
        Call createJpg(sh.Range("C13").Value, sh.Range("C14").Value, "DashboardFile")
        'we attached the embedded image with a Position at 0 (makes the attachment hidden)
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue, 0

        'Then we add an html <img src=''> link to this image
        'Note than you can customize width and height - not mandatory

        .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & "<br><br>" _
            & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'" & "width=width height=heigth><br><br>" _
            & "<br>Best Regards,<br>Ed</font></span>" & .HTMLBody

        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

Set sh = Nothing

End Sub

Sub createJpg(Namesheet As String, nameRange As String, nameFile As String)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
Plage.CopyPicture
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.width, Plage.height)
    .Activate
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
End With
Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

Set Plage = Nothing

End Sub
```