# Call createJpg (reference sheet)

Tags: reference, call

The below code runs a macro and creates the jpeg.
How can I change the name of the sheet (ex:"Strategic") for an active sheet. When I copy a sheet the code don't work anymore, because of the reference name.

```
With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Me@Me.Com"
        .Display
        .Subject = "Strategic Sales"
        .To = "Me@Me.Com"
> Call createJpg("Strategic", "A1:F11", "Quota") '
```

Comment: For those that don't recognize this immediately, can we have the language that this code was written in?

Comment: Be more specific, wich language was used, some code ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27042842/excel-2010-paste-range-and-picture-into-outlook

Comment: Is excel VBA, to create an outlook mail object and embed images. I put the entire code next.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600953/call-createjpg-reference-sheet/36605670#36605670

Answer (score 0):

It's about a code to create an outlook mail objectand embed images

> ```
> Sub sendMail()
>         Application.Calculation = xlManual
>         With Application
>             .ScreenUpdating = False
>             .EnableEvents = False
>         End With
>
>         Dim TempFilePath As String
>
>         'Create a new Microsoft Outlook session
>         Set appOutlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
>         'create a new message
>         Set Message = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
>
>
>         With Message
>             .Subject = "My mail auto Object"
>
>             .HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
>                 & "<p class=style2><span LANG=EN><font FACE=Calibri SIZE=3>" _
>                 & "Hello,<br ><br >The weekly dashboard is available " _
>                 & "<br>Find below an overview :<BR>"
>
>             'first we create the image as a JPG file
>             **Call createJpg("Dashboard", "B8:H9", "DashboardFile")**
>             'we attached the embedded image with a Position at 0 (makes the attachment hidden)
>             TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
>             .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "DashboardFile.jpg", olByValue, 0
>
>             'Then we add an html <img src=''> link to this image
>             'Note than you can customize width and height - not mandatory
>
>             .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<br><B>WEEKLY REPPORT:</B><br>" _
>                 & "<img src='cid:DashboardFile.jpg'" & "width='814' height='33'><br>" _
>                 & "<br>Best Regards,<br>Ed</font></span>"
>
>             .To = "contact1@email.com; contact2@email.com"
>             .Cc = "contact3@email.com"
>
>             .Display
>             '.Send
>         End With
>
>         With Application
>             .ScreenUpdating = True
>             .EnableEvents = True
>         End With
>         Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
>     End Sub
>
> You need to create createJpg function which transform a range into a jpg file.
>
>
> Sub createJpg(Namesheet As String, nameRange As String, nameFile As String)
>     ThisWorkbook.Activate
>     Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
>     Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
>     Plage.CopyPicture
>     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left,
> ```
>
> Plage.Top, Plage.Width, Plage.Height)
>               .Activate
>               .Chart.Paste
>               .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
>           End With
>           Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
>       Set Plage = Nothing
>       End Sub